# Can 'should I be a parent?' be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I'm looking at this question, [Should person with schizophrenia have children?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/23463/254), and wondering whether it can be modified somehow so as to make it on-topic on this site (and/or so as to give the OP the benefit of the experience or knowledge of some of this site's users).

Answer (score 3):

I'd be pretty wary of any variation of "should I be a parent", since it's *de facto* opinion oriented. A site like Buddhism.SE is more able to handle questions involving *should* since it's rooted in a particular ethical/religious perspective, whereas Parenting.SE is open to any.

Comment: Yes (and thank you for answering). I wondered if there was any way to rephrase it to ask for useful or actionable advice in advance -- "Based on your experience, what should I anticipate, what mistakes should I avoid, in what circumstances can this fail or be successful?" -- but maybe that's too general (not asking for specific advice about a specific child/age/society), and/or too specific (e.g. varies too much depending on the would-be parent's condition).